# Adding ld+json script tags in Angular2 component template

Tags: javascript, angular, seo

I have tried too many tricky ways,
such as Renderer2 or ɵDomAdapter,
the script tag is integrated well in the html,
but when loading the url with the structured-data tool of google,
the ld+json script is not rendered !

Is there a way to make google render the page after loading the component ?

Comment: I’d guess that Google’s SDTT simply doesn’t execute JavaScript. Or do you have an example where it works?

Comment: In another project it works fine with Renderer2, [link](https://imgur.com/a/ZFQTC) , Google is parsing the injected js script very well ..

Answer (score 3):

I used this variant in Angular 9 TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-schema-org',
    template: '<div [innerHTML]="jsonLD"></div>',
})
export class SchemaOrgComponent implements OnInit {
    jsonLD: SafeHtml;
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const json = {
            '@context': 'http://schema.org',
            '@type': 'Organization',
            'url': 'https://google.com',
            'name': 'Google',
            'contactPoint': {
                '@type': 'ContactPoint',
                'telephone': '+1-000-000-0000',
                'contactType': 'Customer service',
            },
        };

        // Basically telling Angular this content is safe to directly inject into the dom with no sanitization
        this.jsonLD = this.getSafeHTML(json);
    }

    getSafeHTML(value: {}) {
        const json = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
        const html = `<script type="application/ld+json">${json}</script>`;
        // Inject to inner html without Angular stripping out content
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

And then called it `<app-schema-org></app-schema-org>`

For me the example above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47299603/5155484) has no sense because it imports OnInit and implements OnChange and uses ngOnInit with a parameter for changes.

So here is my working fixed example.

Comment: this insert and div and not a script tag

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. The code below is the best solution I have come up with. This example will also work with Angular Universal.

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div [innerHTML]="jsonLD"></div>'
})
export class JsonLdComponent implements OnChanges {
  jsonLD: SafeHtml;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const json = {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "https://google.com",
      "name": "Google",
      "contactPoint": {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "telephone": "+1-000-000-0000",
        "contactType": "Customer service"
      }
    };

    // Basically telling Angular this content is safe to directly inject into the dom with no sanitization
    this.jsonLD = this.getSafeHTML(json);
  }

  getSafeHTML(value: {}) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
    const html = `${json}`;
    // Inject to inner html without Angular stripping out content
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

I go into more detail in this blog post here https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-seo-with-schema-and-json-ld

I also took this technique and wrapped it up into a npm package to make
it more reusable. https://github.com/coryrylan/ngx-json-ld

Comment: Can we add hide this div do not show on webpage <div [innerHTML]="jsonLD"></div>?  Will it work?

Comment: Here we are expecting script not the div

Comment: this insert and div and not a script tag